# How to get images into ActionColumn Gridview

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have my application standing so far and it looks quite well. The last problem I have to face, is that the application shows a bunch of small pictures outside of the Gridview widged. I am trying to get them back in, so to speak.

So, this is what I have in the ActionColumn:

```
[
    'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
    'template' => '{activate}',
    'buttons' => [
        'activate' => function($url, $model) {
            // Set variable with user ID.
            $userId = $model->iduser;
            // Set teamId to NULL, in case the user is not part of a team yet. Otherwise the site will throw errors.
            $teamId = NULL;
            // Loop through models loeaded by the dataprovider to get the team objects.
            foreach ($model->teamIdteams as $team) {
                // Create variable to get the team id's
                $teamId = $team->idteam;
                // Generate button to activate the user into oncall duty. Only can be used by admins.
                $userHasTeam = UserHasTeam::find()->where(['user_iduser' => $userId])->andWhere(['team_idteam' => $teamId])->all();

                foreach ($userHasTeam as $userHasTeams) {
                    if ($userHasTeams->oncallduty === true) {
                        echo Html::a(Html::img('images/phone.png'));
                    }
                    else if($userHasTeams->oncallduty !== true) {
                        echo Html::a(Html::img('images/phone2.png'), ['activate', 'id' => $userId, 'team' => $teamId]);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest && Yii::$app->user->identity->admin ? true : false,
    ],
],
```

Just to be clear, the images and links work fine, they are just outside of the Grid however. If you guy know how to get them back to place, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Sounds like a CSS problem. Might want to post a screenshot or something.

Also, your first Html::a() call is missing the second parameter.

Comment: Where did you save the images?